# Wrong form data getting submitted in Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing a trivia app that poses a question and takes an answer from one of four buttons in a 2x2 grid. I'm creating each button as a seperate form and adding input data with hidden fields. I'm using remote:true to pass this data to rails through unobtrusive javascript. Unfortunately I'm getting some very strange errors in my quiz app as false answers are sometimes getting passed when the correct answer's button is being pressed. After going over my controller and view for quite some time, I'm convinced that something wonky is happening and the wrong form is being submitted by the browser.

The answer forms in my view are being created like so:

```
<div id="answers">
    <% @choices.each_slice(2) do |first_two| %>
        <div class="row">
         <% first_two.each do |choice| %>
           <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= form_for(@exam, remote: true) do |f| %>
                    <%= hidden_field_tag 'answer', choice.id %>
                    <%= hidden_field_tag 'fIndex', @facts.index(@currentFact) %>
                    <% fact_index = @facts.index(@currentFact) %>
                    <%= f.submit "#{choice.answer}", class: "btn btn-default btn-answer #{answer_size(choice.answer)} ", id: "answer#{choice.id}" %>
                <% end %>
           </div>
         <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

You'll notice that each form has the same id (not good) and class, and I think this is the source of my pain. How would I change this? I would prefer not to do things this way and just pass my form data through a `link_to` helper with method:post, but I don't think that is possible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to give the form an id, you can do that in the form_for's options.  Also, you have fact_index set, but don't seem to be using it... this should work:

```
<%= form_for(@exam, remote: true, id: 'q_' + @exam.id) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'answer', choice.id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'fIndex', @facts.index(@currentFact) %>
  <%= f.submit choice.answer, class: "btn btn-default btn-answer #{answer_size(choice.answer)} ", id: "answer#{choice.id}" %>
<% end %>
```